# Meteor `Please add the Android platform` but next `Platform android already added`

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

#### Source

I do tutorial:

> https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/running-on-mobile

#### Error

I am executing command:

```
 meteor run android-device
```

And obtaining info that *I should add android platform*

```
Please add the Android platform to your project first.
Run: meteor add-platform android
```

But when I run command:

```
meteor add-platform android --verbose
```

Then I get confounding error suggesting that *platform android already added*

```
Adding platform Android to Cordova project    
%% No scripts found for hook "before_platform_add".
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:         

   While adding platform Android to Cordova project:
   Cordova error: Platform android already added.
   at /home/daniel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.3_2.18ygcop++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/platform.js:130:31
   at _fulfilled (/home/daniel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.3_2.18ygcop++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
   at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/daniel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.3_2.18ygcop++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
   at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/daniel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.3_2.18ygcop++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
   at /home/daniel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.3_2.18ygcop++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
   at flush (/home/daniel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.3_2.18ygcop++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
   at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:489:9)
   at process._tickCallback (node.js:418:13)
   => awaited here:
   at Function.Promise.await
   (/home/daniel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.3_2.18ygcop++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:35:12)
   at CordovaProject.runCommands (/tools/cordova/project.js:715:22)
   at CordovaProject.addPlatform (/tools/cordova/project.js:372:10)
   at CordovaProject.ensurePlatformsAreSynchronized (/tools/cordova/project.js:403:12)
   at /tools/cli/commands-cordova.js:60:20
   at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:271:13
   at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
   at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:264:29
   at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
   at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:262:18
   at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
   at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:253:23
   at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
   at Object.capture (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:252:19)
   at Object.main.captureAndExit (/tools/cli/main.js:271:29)
   at Command.func (/tools/cli/commands-cordova.js:42:8)
   at /tools/cli/main.js:1483:23
   (If the error message contains suggestions for a fix, note that this may not apply to the Meteor integration. You can try running again with the --verbose option to help diagnose the issue.)
```

#### Additional info:

Smartphone is connected

```
adb devices
List of devices attached 
b799f64c    device
```

My system info:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

NPM

```
npm -v
3.5.2
```

Compiling by pure Cordova works correctly

Comment: Do you have downloaded Android SDK. There is a package missing from the android SDK i.e. in sdk ---> tools --> there is template folder that must be there but missing from SDK so if you have installed SDK than first check for this folder if that is missing than you need to explicitly download that folder.Thanks

Comment: There was many problems... With caching, permissions, versions of npm. I cleared and purged everything and installed again. Now it works correctly but I cannot reproduce py problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added platform in .meteor/platforms file by hand, stuff can go wrong, so just re-add the platform.

```
meteor remove-platform android
meteor add-platform android
```

Comment: Maybe this is correct answer. I finally removed everything: java, gradle, meteor, node, npm, cordova, android sdk and installed them again. Now everything works and I cannot reproduce my error...